# Linux: Aptitude: Howto replace a dependency by another?

Tags: linux, aptitude, qt

I have a package named libqt4-designer and another package named libqt4-47-designer.
When I do aptitude remove libqt4-designer, Aptitude wants to remove kdesudo and many other applications.
How can I replace the libqt4-designer dependency with libqt4-47-designer?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have to remove it?  What release of Ubuntu are you using?  where did you get `libqt4-47-designer` from?  What repository?

Comment: It's https://launchpad.net/~forumnokia/+archive/fn-ppa .
This is the only ppa I know with the most-latest qt-sources.
I'm using Linux Mint 9 = Ubuntu 10.04 and I want to remove it to have the latest libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `libqt4-47-designer` includes the `Provides: libqt4-designer` it its description, then all you should have to do is install it.  If it doesn't, then you may have leave `libqt4-designer`.

I suppose you could build a dummy package with [equivs](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2005/09/creating-dummy-debian-package-for.html) to replace `libqt4-designer`, but you had better be certain that `libqt4-47-designer` will work as a replacement before you try doing this, you can make a serious mess.

If you look at the `libqt4-47-designer` package description, it does seem to conflict, replace, or break `libqt4-designer`.  Since this is the case, I there should be no reason to remove it, if you did remove it, this package will almost certainly not provided the functionality needed, and you will break your system if you remove it.

```
Package: libqt4-47-designer
Source: qt4-47-x11
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 9076
Maintainer: Kubuntu Developers <kubuntu-devel@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: i386
Version: 4:4.7.2-0fn~lucid0
Replaces: libqt4-47-gui (<< 4.4.0~beta1-1)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libqt4-47-script (= 4:4.7.2-0fn~lucid0), libqt4-47-xml (= 4:4.7.2-0fn~lucid0), libqtcore4-47 (= 4:4.7.2-0fn~lucid0), libqtgui4-47 (= 4:4.7.2-0fn~lucid0), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1)
Breaks: libqt4-47-gui (<< 4.4.0~beta1-1)
```

Comment: It's https://launchpad.net/~forumnokia/+archive/fn-ppa .
This is the only ppa I know with the most-latest qt-sources.